# Type inference rules

Tags: types, syntax, f#

I tried to make a function that takes two characters, takes their ASCII value and returns their XOR. Of course, that works:

```ml
> let a, b = '#', '%' in (int a) ^^^ (int b);;
val it : int = 6
```

This however makes a function that takes integers, which is not the case here.

```ml
> let xor a b  = (int a) ^^^ (int b);;                        

val xor : a:int -> b:int -> int
```

As expected, I can't call this function on previous arguments:

```ml
> let a, b = '#', '%' in xor a b;;

  let a, b = '#', '%' in xor a b;;
  ---------------------------^

/home/cos/stdin(121,28): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    char
```

Why does it happen? How to specify directly the types of arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how:

```
let xor (a: char) (b: char)  = (int a) ^^^ (int b)
```

You can also mark it inline to get a generic function

```
let inline xor a b  = (int a) ^^^ (int b)
```

This will have the type

```
val inline xor :
  a: ^a -> b: ^b -> int
    when  ^a : (static member op_Explicit :  ^a -> int) and
          ^b : (static member op_Explicit :  ^b -> int)
```

and thus work for anything that can be converted to `int`.

The reason that

```
let xor a b  = (int a) ^^^ (int b)
```

is inferred to have type `int -> int -> int` is that for arithmetic operations, F# infers the type `int` by default (See [language specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), page 13)

Comment: And why was it assumed that I want integers? Any docs on the topic?

Comment: F# has to maintain this part of the language spec or else code will break. It is an unfortunate part of the langauge. It would be good to have a "correct type inference" switch that doesn't make guesses; which would not guess that `let square x = x * x` has type `int -> int` and which would not guess record types based on the first few field names.